# PWM output for DAC and using DAC as reference voltage

Tags: arduino, pwm, comparator, dac, voltage-reference

I would like to use a DAC as a programmable reference voltage for a window comparator. The input of the DAC would be the Arduino's PWM output.

Can I connect the Arduino's PWM output directly to the DAC input or should I apply a filter before that?

For the DAC, the reference voltage would be a 5 V Zener reference using a 1 kΩ load resistance from the power supply and two 100 nF capacitors for filtering the signal.

I am thinking mostly about SPI, but I2C interface communication also would be good. Do I need faster communication for DAC control?

Is the output voltage level of the DAC is smooth enough for using directly as a reference voltage for a window comparator?

Or should I use something on the output before applying? The power supply voltage and the reference voltage for the DAC could be the same as 5 V? I am thinking about a 10-bit DAC with a 5 V reference voltage for that. Would the [MCP4911](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22248a.pdf) DAC be good for this task?

Comment: Why don't use another DAC ? Or a dual DAC ?

Comment: filter should work.  just be aware of power usage and your frequency needs.  analog outputs of a DAC can be better

Comment: I don't understand what you need PWM for.